# like to have in-depth knowledge about various type of SignalR transport mechanism (WebSocket ,Server Sent Events,Forever Frame,long polling)

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i like to know how WebSocket ,Server Sent Events,Forever Frame,long polling etc work to establish connection between server & client.

1) what does it mean Server Sent Events and how this works to establish connection between server & client.

2) what does it mean Forever Frame and how this works to establish connection between server & client.

3) what does it mean long polling and how this works to establish connection between server & client.

i read all about transport mechanish from this url **http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr**

but from the above url things were not clear to me because they have not written in detail. so looking for  in-depth knowledge about various type of SignalR transport mechanism & how they establish connection. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Comment: You can also see Fiddler to trace what's being sent to the host.